# How to route to Specific live agent based on Location

Tags: liveagent

How can I route the chat to a live agent based on Location? Is there any standard function I can use? 
Is it possible through code? If yes, then How?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is this problem resolved ??? I am looking for a solution to a similar requirement. Please update me with same.